# Como esconder o fundo de imagens nos app do android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Sou novato em programação estou programando um app no android studio que esta praticamente pronto. Quando copilo ele no meu Moto G2 com android 6.0 funciona perfeitamente no entanto quando copilo no Moto X1 android 5.0 todas as imagens aparecem o fundo se sobrepondo as que ficam embaixo ate mesmo o ícone do app apareceu o fundo o que não acontece no Moto G2 e todas as imagens estão no formato GIF. Não tenho noção de qual pode ser o problema já que funciona no G2 e no X1 não. Se puderem mim ajudar agradeço.[image: Moto G2][image: Moto X1]

Comment: Você usa alguma lib pra exibir as imagens? Elas fazem essa correção por você, da uma pesquisada por Glide ou Picasso, são ótimas.

Answer (score 1):

Opa, tudo bem!?

Para fazer o carregamento de imagens, use alguma biblioteca para carregamento, recomendo o [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), mas tem também o [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Caso queira usar o app offline posteriormente, pelo Glide é possível salvar o cache da imagem, e ela funcionará offline.

> Em caso de uma url para carregamento dinamico

```
GlideApp.with(mContext)
  .load(urlImagem)
  .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
  .into(imageView);
```

> Em caso de imagem local no drawable

```
Glide.with(mContext)
    .load(R.drawable.minhaImagem)
    .into(imageView);
```

> Caso n±ao deseje usar a biblioteca acima, tem essa opção também:

Por padrão, a compactação JPEG armazenaria pixels de plano de fundo transparentes na cor preta. Então, é melhor evitar compactá-lo como JPEG.

Se você deseja armazenar e recuperar imagens PNG, armazene suas imagens de origem no formato PNG e, em seguida, recupere-as.

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
```

Answer (score 0):

O ideal é que as imagens do seu aplicativo estejam no formato ***png*** (não obrigatóriamente) para que possam se comportar da mesma forma em todos os dispositivos e que de preferência tenham fundo transparente. Além disso você também pode usar bibliotecas como [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) para trabalhar com imagens, dê uma olhada nesse artigo do Google falando como tratar as imagens (*9-patch*) para seu app, [9-patch](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html).